# Custom django field type, with modified column look up in SELECT part

Tags: django, django-orm

I would like to implement a custom Django field type. Namely a TranslatedField that is backed by native json/jsonb using postgres.

But I would also like it to not have to return all translations for a particular query. Something like this:

```
class TranslatedField(JSONField):
    pass


class MyModel(models.Model):

    name = TranslatedField()
```

And then used in an example:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.create(name={'en': 'Duck', 'fr': 'Canard'})
>>> set_language('fr')  # Imagine this function sets a global variable
>>> en_fr = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
>>> en_fr.name
>>> 'Canard'
```

Which is fine, I can do that by returning the whole 'name' json from the database. But I would prefer if django issued actual SQL like this that did the lookup in postgres and saved me some bytes across the network:

```
SELECT 'name'->'fr' FROM 'mymodel';
```

Does Django have any hooks that let me dynamically change the 'SELECT' part of the query?

Comment: You probably could, but how would you want this to work in practice? What would happen on save? Would you ever want to return the whole of the JSON content?

Comment: On save I'd directly modify the particular json key, and I'd have another method for overwriting the whole jsonb field. Ultimately it wouldn't matter if it was kind of read only. Except for a rare "update translations" event